# How to locate a font in Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts

Ubuntu desktop with 12.04 is about to crash.  Installed 13.04 on a new machine, want to transfer Book Antiqua font from old machine to the new one.  How do I find it on the old machine?  My `/usr` directory is empty.

My `fonts.conf` file has these lines:

```
<!-- Font directory list -->
<dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>
<dir>/usr/x11R6/lib/X11/fonts</dir> 
<dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
<dir>~/.fonts</dir>
```

Don't know what this means, but my `/usr` directory has nothing in it.

Answer (score 62):

I use `fc-list` command to view the list of fonts installed.

Comment: Hey, thanks. This was a really helpful one.
Also, I guess *-list must be a really helpful command in general.

Comment: `fc-list | grep "<(partial) name of the font>"` maybe handy

Comment: Very useful for showing font properties as well, e.g. `fc-list : family style file spacing`, see [docs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/fc-list.1.html). Properties are listed [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/fonts-conf.5.html).

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski Excellent! Don't forget everyone, this is case sensitive. Been killing myself until this answer.

Answer (score 42):

> **Secret Locations:**
>
> The secret locations of your fonts whereabouts are defined in
>   `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`.
>
> ```
> gedit /etc/fonts/fonts.conf
> ```
>
> **Standard Locations:**
>
> ```
> /usr/share/fonts
> /usr/local/share/fonts
> /home/<username>/.fonts #where <username> is your user name
> ```
>
> Note that the `.fonts` folder is a hidden folder.

Source: [Where Are Fonts Stored / Located In Ubuntu?](http://www.vitalbodies.com/blog/2008/07/21/where-are-fonts-stored-located-in-ubuntu-hardy-heron/)

Comment: Additionally to above: `/home/<username>/.local/share/fonts`

Comment: under Ubuntu 20.x that requires root privileges to see, i.e.  `sudo cat  /etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

Answer (score 23):

I've found that fonts can be installed for Precise (12.04) and Trusty (14.04) in

```
~/.local/share/fonts
```

Comment: Now this is really surprising! This location is definitely *not* in my `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` and even so all fonts I installed using Ubuntu's font viewer ended up there.

Comment: Not "can", they "are" installed there when using the Font Viewer to install them. I am already spending hours on finding this location to get rid of a font. Pretty dull.

Comment: This doesn't actually work on 12.04. Use `~/.fonts` instead.

Answer (score 3):

To know where are fonts, ask Ubuntu in a terminal:

```
 whereis fonts
```

Sample reply:

```
 fonts: /etc/fonts /usr/share/fonts
```

The first path has the fonts.conf file which specifies font settings and other locations.
The second one is what you are looking for as the default fonts system directory.