# How can I determine which fonts are installed from the command line, and what is the easiest way to install more?

Tags: command-line, fonts, beagleboard, .ttf

There are many questions and answers regarding fonts on Ubuntu, but not so many dealing with Ubuntu for Embedded Linux, such as Beaglebone Black.

I have not been able to locate any .ttf files in standard locations on my system, and I think that given the resource constraints these have been omitted.

Using the command line, how can I (1)  find out which fonts are installed, and (2) install more fonts.

FYI:  I am looking for a simple sans-serif ttf that I can use to display text on an 8x8 LED matrix.

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/share/fonts`? A very basic way to list fonts is `fc-list`.

Comment: /usr/share/fonts isn't there.  fc-list command is not found.  so far I just downloaded a free arial font from www.dafont.com and used secure copy to transfer it to my beaglebone.  i will create a /usr/share/fonts/ directory manually for future use.  scp /Users/me/Downloads/pixel_arial_11/PIXEARG_.TTF ubuntu@192.168.7.2:/home/ubuntu/

Comment: Try this: [How to locate a font in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/353307/how-to-locate-a-font-in-ubuntu), [How to install fonts fast and easy?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/191778/how-to-install-fonts-fast-and-easy) and [How do I install fonts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The best and simplest way is to use console command (this command should be available for all ubuntu-based distributions) :

`fc-list`

Example output (stripped) :

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Medium.ttf: Lato,Lato Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg/TlwgTypo-Bold.ttf: Tlwg Typo:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-SemiboldItalic.ttf: Lato,Lato Semibold:style=Semibold Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Serif:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansThai-Regular.ttf: Noto Sans Thai:style=Regular
...
```

From MAN :

```
fc-list - list available fonts
```

To check all available options use MAN (manual): `man fc-list`

Comment: `sudo apt install fontconfig` to install, e.g. if you are getting a `fc-list: command not found` error

Answer (score 15):

if you need to get the font family name:

`fc-list : family | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 4):

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

(1) Thanks to the links from Lety, on my ubuntu 15.04 machine `less /etc/fonts/fonts.conf`. In there it describes how to use local.conf.

(2) from a command line, to search for more fonts I use `apt-cache search font | grep lcd` then I use `apt-cache show {}` (replacing {} with the package name) for a more detailed description. installation from the command line has several variants (like aptitude) but good old `sudo apt-get install {}` works well.

Answer (score 4):

Answer for 2nd question:

Installing font is just copying its file to some folder. There can be many folders. At my system they are:

- `/usr/share/fonts/` — fonts for all users
- `~/.local/share/fonts/` - fonts for particular user

There can be any subfolders you want.

Here is the command to get list of font files that your system uses.

```
fc-list -f '%{file}\n' | sort
```

Look at it and you'll get the idea of where fonts in your system located/