# What is the default set of fonts available to web browsers after installation

Tags: system-installation, fonts

I don't have an install of Ubuntu but am hoping this community can answer a question for me — I am trying to build a CSS font stack that includes a font the majority of Ubuntu users will have available. I am looking for a font family as close to Tobias Frere-Jones' [Gotham](https://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/overview) as possible.

We use three weights via `@font-face`; Light, Book and Medium, each with its accompanying italic, so the fallback font should also have six equivalent faces available. So far I have chosen Helvetica Neue for Macs and Segoe UI for Windows 7+ users.

What are the default font faces installed by Ubuntu [not just families, but weights, italic/oblique, small-caps faces too if any]; and of those that have three or more weights with italic, which would be suitable as a fallback for Gotham? (sans-serif, modernist, somewhat geometric)

Comment: If you need a special font, ensure it's available. You cannt trust in some "default".

Comment: @frlan That's the whole point of CSS's fallback mechanism: you can't trust that the font you want will be available. Hence my need to find common look-a-like fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following options:

- **Purchase WOFF2 font files** to use on your site via CSS.
- **Find a suitable typeface on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/).** After selecting some that you like, "Customize" to select the weights you want. Then follow the "Embed" instructions to use on your site.
- Hope that users have sane defaults for `serif`, `sans-serif`, and `monotype`.

---

The default font set often changes. There is no guarantee that any particular font will be installed. Most fonts do not have all the weights you desire.

- Ubuntu systems likely have **Ubuntu** installed.
- Fedora and Red Hat systems may have **Overpass** installed. It is not currently available in Ubuntu repositories.
- **DejaVu** was once used as the default on GNOME. Some still keep it around.
- The current GNOME default is **Cantarell**. Many are likely to have it installed.
- KDE users are likely to have **Oxygen** installed.
- **Noto** is favored for its broad multilingual support.
- Some font sets are automatically substituted when Arial, Times New Roman, or Courier are requested.

  - **Liberation**. Often installed with LibreOffice.
  - **Croscore**. Calibri and Cambria substitutes are available in **Croscore Extra**.
  - **TeXGyre**. Based on originals by URW.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [other reports](https://askubuntu.com/a/866951/385262) with the fc-list command, what I have got on a generic Ubuntu 12.04 VM are:

```
Liberation Mono:style=Regular
Umpush:style=Oblique
Saab:style=Regular
Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Italic
Liberation Sans Narrow:style=Regular
FreeMono:style=Oblique,наклонен,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,oblic,Курсив,İtalik,huruf miring,похилий,ležeče,slīpraksts,pasvirasis,nghiêng,Etzana
URW Palladio L:style=Roman
Century Schoolbook L:style=Bold Italic
Liberation Sans:style=Regular
Lohit Punjabi:style=Regular
mry_KacstQurn:style=Regular
Norasi:style=Oblique
FreeSans:style=Oblique,наклонен,kurzíva,kursiv,Cursiva,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,kursywa,Itálico,oblic,Курсив,İtalik,huruf miring,похилий,Ležeče,slīpraksts,pasvirasis,nghiêng,Etzana
TlwgTypewriter:style=Oblique
Liberation Serif:style=Bold Italic
Ubuntu Mono:style=Bold
TlwgMono:style=Medium
Tlwg Typo:style=Medium
Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold
OpenSymbol:style=Regular
Norasi:style=BoldOblique
Ubuntu,Ubuntu Light:style=Light,Regular
Tlwg Typo:style=BoldOblique
Purisa:style=BoldOblique
URW Chancery L:style=Medium Italic
Bitstream Charter:style=Bold Italic
Ubuntu:style=Bold Italic
Ubuntu Mono:style=Bold Italic
Mukti Narrow,à¦®à§à¦•à§à¦¤à¦¿:style=Regular
KacstOne:style=Bold
Pothana2000:style=Regular,Pothana2000
Liberation Sans Narrow:style=Bold
Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Regular
Loma:style=Oblique
Century Schoolbook L:style=Bold
Century Schoolbook L:style=Italic
Ubuntu Mono:style=Regular
Mukti Narrow,মুক্তি  পাতনা,Mukti Narrow Bold:style=Regular,Bold
Khmer OS:style=Regular
WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono,文泉驛等寬微米黑,文泉驿等宽微米黑:style=Regular
KacstDecorative:style=Medium
Norasi:style=BoldItalic
gargi:style=Medium
Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular
Ubuntu:style=Bold
KacstBook:style=Medium
URW Palladio L:style=Italic
Garuda:style=Oblique
Meera:style=Regular
Mallige:style=Bold
Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Condensed
TlwgTypewriter:style=Medium
URW Gothic L:style=Demi
Liberation Serif:style=Bold
Liberation Mono:style=Bold Italic
Liberation Sans Narrow:style=Italic
Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Medium Italic
Bitstream Charter:style=Regular
Purisa:style=Bold
Garuda:style=BoldOblique
Nimbus Mono L:style=Bold Oblique
Kinnari:style=Medium
Norasi:style=Italic
Dingbats:style=Regular
TlwgMono:style=Bold
FreeSans:style=Bold,получерен,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,gros,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,huruf tebal,жирний,Krepko,treknraksts,pusjuodis,đậm,Lodia
Loma:style=BoldOblique
Waree:style=Oblique
NanumMyeongjo,나눔명조:style=Bold
Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Medium
Kedage:style=Bold
Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Italic
Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold Italic
KacstOffice:style=Medium
Ubuntu:style=Italic
FreeMono:style=Bold,получерен,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,gros,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,huruf tebal,жирний,polkrepko,treknraksts,pusjuodis,đậm,Lodia
Nimbus Mono L:style=Regular
Umpush:style=Book
Umpush:style=Bold
Norasi:style=Regular
Khmer OS System:style=Regular
FreeSans:style=BoldOblique,получерен наклонен,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,FettKursiv,Έντονη Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,GrasItalique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,VetCursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,gros oblic,Обычный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,huruf tebal miring,жирний похилий,polkrepko ležeče,treknais  slīpraksts,pusjuodis pasvirasis,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
Bitstream Charter:style=Italic
URW Gothic L:style=Book
FreeSerif:style=Italic,курсивен,kurzíva,kursiv,Λειψίας,Cursiva,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,kursywa,Itálico,cursiv,Курсив,ตัวเอียง,İtalik,kursif,Ležeče,kursīvs,kursivas,nghiêng,Etzana
Kinnari:style=Oblique
KacstLetter:style=Medium
KacstFarsi:style=Medium
Sawasdee:style=Bold
Liberation Sans:style=Bold
TlwgTypewriter:style=Bold
KacstNaskh:style=Medium
Rachana:style=Regular
Rekha:style=Medium
Waree:style=BoldOblique
Tlwg Typist:style=BoldOblique
Courier 10 Pitch:style=Italic
FreeSerif:style=BoldItalic,получерен курсивен,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,FettKursiv,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,gros cursiv,Обычный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,ตัวเอียงหนา,Kalın İtalik,huruf tebal kursif,жирний курсив,Polkrepko Pežeče,treknais kursīvs,pusjuodis kursyvas,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
TlwgTypewriter:style=BoldOblique
Liberation Serif:style=Regular
Purisa:style=Medium
KacstScreen:style=Medium,KacstScreen
KacstTitle:style=Medium
Tlwg Typist:style=Bold
Tlwg Typo:style=Oblique
Kinnari:style=BoldItalic
Kinnari:style=BoldOblique
Liberation Sans:style=Bold Italic
Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Condensed Italic
Norasi:style=Bold
URW Bookman L:style=Demi Bold
URW Bookman L:style=Light
FreeMono:style=Medium,нормален,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,µεσαία,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,menengah,прямій,navadno,vidējs,normalusis,thường,Arrunta
URW Gothic L:style=Demi Oblique
FreeSerif:style=Bold,получерен,tučné,fed,Fett,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,gros,Обычный,Fet,ตัวหนา,Kalın,huruf tebal,жирний,Polkrepko,treknraksts,pusjuodis,đậm,Lodia
Standard Symbols L:style=Regular
Mallige:style=Normal
ori1Uni,utkal:style=Medium
Sawasdee:style=Regular
Ubuntu,Ubuntu Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
KacstTitleL:style=Medium,Regular
Courier 10 Pitch:style=Regular
Liberation Mono:style=Bold
WenQuanYi Micro Hei,文泉驛微米黑,文泉驿微米黑:style=Regular
Vemana2000,Pothana2000:style=Regular,Pothana2000
KacstArt:style=Medium
Lohit Hindi:style=Regular
URW Palladio L:style=Bold
Nimbus Sans L:style=Regular Condensed
KacstDigital:style=Medium
FreeMono:style=BoldOblique,получерен наклонен,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,gros oblic,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,huruf tebal miring,жирний похилий,polkrepko ležeče,treknais  slīpraksts,pusjuodis pasvirasis,Lodi etzana
Sawasdee:style=BoldOblique
KacstPoster:style=Medium
Loma:style=Bold
Loma:style=Book
URW Bookman L:style=Light Italic
Umpush:style=Light
Phetsarath OT:style=Regular
FreeSans:style=Medium,нормален,obyčejné,normal,Mittel,µεσαία,Normaali,Normál,Medio,Gemiddeld,Odmiana Zwykła,Обычный,Normálne,menengah,прямій,Navadno,vidējs,normalusis,vừa,Arrunta
Century Schoolbook L:style=Roman
TlwgMono:style=Oblique
Nimbus Roman No9 L:style=Regular Italic
TlwgMono:style=BoldOblique
Courier 10 Pitch:style=Bold
Garuda:style=Book
Garuda:style=Bold
Lohit Tamil:style=Regular
DejaVu Sans:style=Bold
DejaVu Sans:style=Book
Ubuntu:style=Regular
TakaoPGothic,Takao Pゴシック:style=Regular
Kinnari:style=Italic
URW Gothic L:style=Book Oblique
FreeSerif:style=Medium,нормален,obyčejné,normal,Mittel,µεσαία,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Gemiddeld,odmiana zwykła,Обычный,Normálne,ปกติ,menengah,прямій,Navadno,vidējs,normalusis,vừa,Arrunta
URW Palladio L:style=Bold Italic
Kinnari:style=Bold
Untitled1:style=Medium
NanumGothic,나눔고딕:style=Bold
Ubuntu Mono:style=Italic
NanumMyeongjo,나눔명조:style=Regular
KacstQurn:style=Medium,Regular
Sawasdee:style=Oblique
NanumGothic,나눔고딕:style=Regular
Nimbus Mono L:style=Regular Oblique
Symbol:style=Regular
Lohit Gujarati:style=Regular
Liberation Sans Narrow:style=Bold Italic
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold
Liberation Serif:style=Italic
KacstOne:style=Regular
Umpush:style=BoldOblique
Kedage:style=Normal
Lohit Bengali:style=Regular
Umpush:style=LightOblique
Nimbus Mono L:style=Bold
Ubuntu Condensed:style=Regular
Liberation Mono:style=Italic
Tlwg Typist:style=Medium
Bitstream Charter:style=Bold
Waree:style=Book
Waree:style=Bold
Nimbus Sans L:style=Bold Condensed Italic
URW Bookman L:style=Demi Bold Italic
Tlwg Typist:style=Oblique
Tlwg Typo:style=Bold
Liberation Sans:style=Italic
KacstPen:style=Medium
Purisa:style=Oblique
DejaVu Serif:style=Book
DejaVu Serif:style=Bold
```

Umpush Light appears to be the closest choice to gothamsm-light.

Comment: Umpush is a family of Thai fonts. Anyone who doesn't speak Thai would *not* be expected to have it installed.