# List of pre installed fonts in ubuntu

Tags: fonts

I have a question, I need one font from Ubuntu 16,04, which is not in Windows, I dont remember name. Is there any list of preinstalled fonts in Ubuntu? 
I dont have ubuntu anymore so I dont know how to get it :D

Comment: You can download the `live-cd` version run it and then check this answer : https://askubuntu.com/questions/552979/how-can-i-determine-which-fonts-are-installed-from-the-command-line-and-what-is/866951#866951 on how to get the list of fonts.

Comment: This page is made 7 years ago but might be still useful: http://www.apaddedcell.com/web-fonts This is 10 years old: http://www.ars-informatica.ca/article.php?article=59 Also, see: https://www.ostechnix.com/find-installed-fonts-commandline-linux/

Answer (score 4):

You can use Ubuntu `live-cd` option for this. Follow the guide here on how to obtain the `iso` image of the Ubuntu distribution:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

After You run the `live-cd` on PC, open terminal and issue this command:

`fc-list`

It will list all installed fonts on the distribution.

Example output:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Medium.ttf: Lato,Lato Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg/TlwgTypo-Bold.ttf: Tlwg Typo:style=Bold
```

Comment: I'd be interested in the actual list, since I don't have ubuntu installed.

Comment: @AdrianLopez Using the live CD, you don't have to install anything. Just pop in the CD and reboot.