# Where does TeXlive 2014 locate font files on Ubuntu 14.10 ?

Tags: fonts, latex, texlive

I have a supposedly trivial question and I'm having a hard time finding an answer.

How can I determine the directories where `fontspec` is looking for OTF files?

I want to edit `FontAwesome.otf` with fontforge following these instructions:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134244/76715

On an **Ubuntu 14.10** machine with **TeX Live 2014** installed I edited this font and saved a duplicate in the following directories because I found copies or links to `FontAwesome.otf`.

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public

/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public
```

After editing the corresponding cls file XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX still can't find the new font.

I installed the FontAwesome package by `sudo apt-get install fonts-font-awesome`. The FontAwesome TeX package was downloaded automatically. I don't know whether this downloaded another copy of the font.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/353307/how-to-locate-a-font-in-ubuntu